# error 404 when using absolute url

Tags: html, email, absolute-path

I'm creating a html email. Everything is working fine except the link to view the email in a browser. The page was added a couple of weeks after the rest of the site and is definitely on my server but when I click on it I get a 404 error, link is broken etc. 
To try to fix this I have done the following: 
Originally the page was stored in a folder named 'newsletter'. I have since moved the file out of the folder in to the root directory and changed the URL to match.
I have renamed the file to remove underscores and anything else other than letters and changed the URL to match.
I have verified that the file is definitely on the server using Filezilla and through the hosting company's site.
I changed the URL to a filename of a page which is already in the site. When I click on the link it opens this page no problem.
I have emptied the cache and history of all browsers.
I have typed the URL in to Safari and other browsers but I still get the 404 error.

There is another link on the page to the homepage and it works fine.
Any help would be very much appreciated. 
Below is the HTML:

```
<td valign="top" width="180">
<div style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10px; line-height:100%; text-align:left;">
Is this email not displaying correctly?<br />
<a href="http://www.familymatters.ie/email.html" target="_blank" style="color: #76a007;     text-decoration: none;">View it in your browser</a>.
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: The link http://www.familymatters.ie/email.html definitely does not work. There could be many reasons: file permissions etc

Comment: @BigBadOwl The link works for me though..

Comment: Wow i has forgotten how fast static html pages could be. On topic: Try removing the _blank.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. DickieBoy I tried removing the _blank. Still not working.

Comment: I tested again this morning (UK) and I see the page www.familymatters.ie/email.html. It may have been some kind of server caching because I certainly did not see it yesterday.